# How do I stop a directive from executing until a given time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an async function that retrieves data from the server, and I have a directive that is supposed to display the data of whatever that async function retrieves.

What I am trying to do is to place an ng-show in false in my directive, supposing that the directive will not load unless I place the ng-show in true.
The ng-show would remain false until my async function retrieves the data.

The thing is this is not working, the directive would load regardless of if I place an ng-show or not on it - any other ideas?

This is what I have tried in code :

Js :

```
 getFile.then(function (result) {
                        $scope.show = true;
                        Utilities.safeApply($scope);
                    })
```

Html :

```
section class="list file-list group" ng-show="show" view-mode="assets">
    <file file="model.file"></file>
</section>
```

Directive :

```
.directive('file', ['$rootScope', '$compile', function($rootScope, $compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'file.html',
            scope: {
                show: '='
            },
            controller: function($scope) {
                //do stuff here once async function finished
            }
```

Comment: It is definitely doable, but it's a little difficult to help you without looking at your code. Please, update the question to show what you have tried (and also, if you can, prepare a plunker).

Comment: Added some source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and ngHide merely show and hide content, they don't conditionally add it or remove it from the page. If you really want that behavior, look into [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

**However**, I think your problem would be better solved setting up a watcher in your directive that acts when the content is ready. This is a "more angular" way of approaching the problem, since it relies on data-binding.

```
.directive('file', ['$rootScope', '$compile', function($rootScope, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'file.html',
        scope: {
            file: '=', // YOU DIDN'T HAVE THIS YET
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('file', function (newValue) {
                if (!newValue) { return; }
                // do async code here. $scope.file will be defined
            };
        }
```

As the other poster mentioned, you *may* have to call $scope.$apply() to fire a digest cycle after receiving the result of your Ajax call. It depends on the what your `getFile` method looks like. If it uses one of Angular's core services, like [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http), you probably won't need to manually mess with the digest cycles.

Comment: adding a watch actually does the trick, but I am wondering, placing file='=' doesnt already create a watch internally???

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. The `file: '='` merely defines what `file` means in the isolated scope of your directive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling $scope.$apply() at the end of (or after) your function? This works for me in similar situations. I think it has something to do with updating the $scope from outside of angular.

Disclaimer: I don't know if this is good practice, but I've been forced to use it a few times working with async functions and it does what I want it to do